# Changes are lost after Git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have checked out a new branch and I have made a commit. In that commit there is one  file 'A' with no changes but still showing as changed. After that I am using

```
git fetch
```

command I get some commits from upstream, then I use

```
git rebase
```

As I do it I get one conflict in file 'A'.

I add it and I use

```
git rebase --continue
```

after this

```
git rebase
```

process is done and my changes from commit are gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember:  rebase is overwriting your history.  You should only use this command with great caution.

Answer (score 4):

If the file was ever committed, have a look at the output of `git reflog`. It will show you all commits git created lately. That includes commits that were either created temporarily, or that are not reachable anymore via branches.

If `A` was ever committed, one of the listed commits should include it. If you had only local changes and rebased anyway, I'm not sure you can recover it at all.

Comment: I recovered my code using 
        `git reflog`
and then i had to merge.
i just want to know why after
        `git rebase`
my changes are lost

Comment: Hard to say from the description you gave. The simple answer is: If you added your changes during the conflict resolution, they would be still there. You'd have to show some situation where you can reproduce it and the exact commands you use.

Comment: Below are the steps i followed

        `1.git checkout branch 2. git add . 3. git commit -m "message" 4. git fetch 5. git rebase `

after this i get conflict as crlf change.
then 
        `7. git add . 8. git rebase --continue`
and changes are lost after that

Comment: I can't reproduce it. All changes stay as expected.

Comment: ohh i will comment here again if i encounter same scenario ever.

Comment: I had the issue of rebase losing files. There was a conflict during rebase which was resolved. After completing rebase, I noticed that all the other changes in the commit with the conflict were lost. I had Visual Studio and VS Code open in the rebase project and closing them allowed the rebase to go successfully.